# Is there any reason not to add goals to the unfiltered raw data view in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up goals in my master view that has filters on it. I was thinking it would make sense to add these same goals to my unfiltered view that way if I ever need to investigate how a certain filter is affecting any of the goals I can reference the goals on the unfiltered view as a baseline comparison.

Mainly I want to ensure that adding goals to an unfiltered view would not alter the incoming data in any way - this way all the data will still be truly unfiltered. As far as I know, adding goals would not do this. Is that correct? And are there any other reasons to not add goals to an unfiltered view?

I have searched online and can't find any answers related to this. It seems to me like adding your goals to your unfiltered view would be a good practice, but I can't find anything online saying so, so I am wondering if there is a reason not to do this that I am missing.

Comment: There is no right answer to this; it's entirely up to you how you want to organise it. You can always have another unfiltered view and add to your goals to that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

If there is no consensus on a best practice regarding this, then the only question I need answered in order to decide what I'll do is "Will adding goals to a view in any way alter the incoming data?"

Comment: No, goals do not alter data. Personally, I would still recommend copying the unfiltered view and setting it up in there.

Comment: Thanks. In that case I will add my goals to my unfiltered view because I'd rather not clutter up my views with an additional copy of my unfiltered view. What is the reason you why you recommend copying the unfiltered view instead?